# Is there any way to continue execution on a raised unforeseen exception in vscode debugger?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I made a typo on a variable in my script. Unfortunately, I did not see it before I began debugging.

After 20 minutes of runtime, the script reached the piece of code with the misnamed variable, and it raised an ValueError Exception, which was break into.

Using the console, I can reassign the value to the variable, this time with its proper name. However, after an exception is raised, it seems there's no way around to continue execution. Is this true?

Is there any method of forcing/bypassing a particular uncaught exception breakpoint so I don't have to restart my script and wait 20 minutes all over again just because of a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pdb: resume code execution after exception caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423637/python-pdb-resume-code-execution-after-exception-caught)

Comment: Note that this case is even worse than the nominated duplicate—it could easily be the case that the function in question would have to be recompiled to use the console’s value.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you want to somehow suppress the exception mid-raise to allow continued execution by pretending the exception never occurred. If that's correct then the answer is no as Python doesn't provide a way to do this.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I would use this feature all the time. Good subject for a new PEP?